# client.images.get(Image_name) doesn't pull imge

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-container

I am trying to get an image in a conatiner but it gives an error

> docker.errors.ImageNotFound: 404 Client Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.42/images/ImageName:latest/json: Not Found ("No such image: ImageName:latest")

```
import docker    
client = docker.from_env()
client.images.get("IMAGE_NAME")
client.containers.run(
        image=IMAGE_NAME,
        *other vars)
```

Comment: Did you read the error? Does that image exist?

Comment: Yes it does exist. I did pull it before I get it.